# Using PS4/XB1 in a country before release date?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

As the title says, can the PS4 and/or XBOX One be used to **play online and/or offline in a region where they have not yet been released?** I am thinking of ordering a system from the US and play in a country (Thailand) where neither have been released yet.

Comment: This really should be split into 2 separate questions, one per console.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Xbox One in Luxembourg where it wasn't released and never will as the country is not supported by Live. I am using an UK account and am fine. I hit the rare IP locked content but using a VPN I can get it anyway. The worst you could have to suffer is migrate your account to a region supported by Live.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Did you need a UK credit card in order to access Live or just made a UK address up?

Comment: I am using Paypal for all my transactions on the console. However, I used a Luxebmourgish credit card on my Windows Phone on my, then still, German account and it worked fine. I am not 100% sure how that worked. Using Paypal is just fine as you need not worry about your card. However, the same does not hold true for the Playstation Network. I could not link my Paypal account and had to use my credit card!

Answer (score 0):

you should be fine, Games for at least the PS4 are Region Free, however multiplayer with both will need a subscription to their services.

While i don't think there is any problem with getting a console from the US and fixing up an account in Thailand and using that keep in mind that there maybe some stuff in the US Playstation Network or X-Box Live meant for the PS4/X-Box One which you wont be able to get in a Thailand account until the consoles have been released, there may also be a problem with console registration if your using a Thailand account when registering your console.

Keep in mind however that DLC is still region locked to the same region as that of where you brought the game, so if you get a US Game you will need a US Account in order to get DLC, DLC from a Thailand account will most likely be incompatible with US Games (though with that said, UK and Australian DLC is interchangeable but Nintendo counts them both as PAL)

Answer (score 0):

I live in the Netherlands, where the Xbox One is still not sold, but I bought one in Germany.

One thing I had to do was migrate my account from the Netherlands to the US and set my Xbox One to the US as well. (Any country will do, as long as they match) The problem with this was that my Microsoft Points from my X360 didn't migrate along, so I had to use them up on my X360 before migrating (I could not use them on the Xbox One).

After that everything works fine and I can play online, download and buy new games with my PayPal account, etc.

Microsoft Netherlands has officially made a statement that they fully support imported Xbox Ones, so that's an added benefit for us.